# Transactions and PHP

Tags: php, transactions

I have been trying to make such functionality that will make sure that on click all the values are being stored in the multiple tables of the database successfully. I read an article about it and it says :

" In PHP there are no such methods and the we must use the direct SQL. (In PHP PDO there are such methods.) "

Kindly let me know is it possible to embed begin transaction and end transaction in an sql query only because i never worked on PDO and the only idea i have is to make multiple insertion to tables in one SQL query.

**Rough idea**

```
<?php
$sql = " 
Begin Transaction
insert into .............
insert into ...........
End Transaction "
mysql_query($sql) ?>
```

---

SOLUTION THAT I FOUND:

```
mysql_select_db($database_dany, $dany);
  if (mysql_query('BEGIN')) {
    if (
        mysql_query($query1)  &&
        mysql_query($query2)  &&
        mysql_query($query3) &&
        mysql_query($insertSQL) 
        )
        $result = mysql_query('COMMIT'); // both queries looked OK, save
    else
    {
        mysql_query('ROLLBACK'); // problems with queries, no changes
        echo "There are some problemo!!!";
        }
```

Comment: If you have not started to work with PDO yet, maybe you should. [This would help, i guess](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: you should catch errors at mysql_query and then rollback, the return false is not enough

Comment: good idea i'll keep that in mind while working on my code thanks..

Answer (score 0):

That will vary based on the db that you use.  The mysql documentation page on the subject:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html

```
 START TRANSACTION;
 SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
 UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
 COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple rows using the following syntax:

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val1.1', 'val1.2', 'val1.3')
   INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val2.1', 'val2.2', 'val2.3')
   INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val3.1', 'val3.2', 'val3.3')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

If you want to more infomation about this please check this link http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php