# Scroll to certain div with url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can i send the request to load certain div with a url only something like abc.com/#header1 cause the approach i am using i have to make 5 separate files for my task and update all of them. 
If it can be done by including any piece of code in my one file then it'll be best for me.

I want the scroll on div with the url request something like abc.com/#def where def is the id of the div the page should load.

Comment: or something like abc.com?div=header1 and the value gets by html page and perform the functionality accordingly

Comment: http://example.org/#header1 scrolls to header1 anchor by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In relation to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071000/trigger-div-on-pageload/11071020#11071020), this is how you can do it:

```
$(function(){
  // get hash value
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  // now scroll to element with that id
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top });
});
```

You need to put that code in page where you want element to scroll. So if you visit `yourdomain.com/#foo`, it would scroll to an element with `id` set to `foo`.

Comment: can i add time delay to your function?

Comment: @softgenic: Yes you can, there is that argument for `animate` function, see its docs.

Comment: yeah bhai i did it thanks alot.. can you also please check this issue I have found its solution but i have some doubts in mind wheter it'll work or not . Kindly check if the mentioned solution in my question is right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873034/transactions-and-php

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to load some url in particular div within the page.

```
 Here is an example with fraction of code :    
 $('#result').load('test.html', function() {
   alert('Hello,I am in the div');
});
```

If you need the data of that particular url to be shown.Then,you can use Ajax along with Jquery.

```
   Here is a small code for it:
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#result").load(function(){

          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost/a.html",
            success:function(data){
             alert(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
   });
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try this : document.getElementById('elmID').scrollIntoView(true);